# Access Database updation query

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

I have an access database of employees. Now i want to increment 10,000 to the salary of those employees having salary > 50,000 and want to increment 5000 to the salary of those employees having salary < 50,000 ...

```
update employee
set 
( 
if emp_salary > 50000 
emp_salary = emp_salary + 10000;
else
emp_salary = emp_salary + 5000;
)
where (???)
```

please complete this update query of SQL ...

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax simply makes no sense.  In MS Access, you should be using the `iif()` function for conditionals (in any other database, this would be a `case` expression).

```
update employee
    set emp_salary = emp_salary + iif(emp_salary > 50000, 10000, 5000)
    where (???);
```